# Prevent text from wrapping when writing to PDF File

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, file-io, pdf-writer

My project is suppose to read text from an excel file that has been converted to a PDF. Once the information is read, the code is suppose to take certain lines from the pdf excel sheet and write them to a PDF. The problem is that there is a long line of text that wraps when it writes to the new pdf file.

Example: 
"Accounting Codes: A Give Money || B Give More Money || C Missed To Many Days || D New Hire || E Late Submission || F Check Vacation Days|| G Overtime Worked "

How would I get this to fit on one line on the PDF file?

Comment: Increase the page width or decrease the font size/margins is what I would try.

Comment: I have tried that but that does not work either